# Extract text from parentheses in Excel

Tags: excel, excel-formula

I have an Excel list where I need text that exists within parenthesis.
e.g.

| From | Gene name | Column I need |
| --- | --- | --- |
| O70257 | syntaxin 7(Stx7) | Stx7 |
| Q7TQ90 | alcohol dehydrogenase 5 (class III), chi polypeptide(Adh5) | Adh5 |

I tried the following function, as suggested in a previous answer here:

```
=MID(text,SEARCH("(",text)+1,SEARCH(")",text)-SEARCH("(",text)-1)
```

It works for the first row, but for the second it only returns the first parenthesis content (class III). Is there a way to only take the text contained in the parentheses at the end?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You may try this as shown in the image below,

Formula used in cell **C2**

```
=SUBSTITUTE(TRIM(RIGHT(SUBSTITUTE(B2,"(",REPT(" ",100)),100)),")","")
```

Another way,

```
=SUBSTITUTE(FILTERXML("<t><s>"&SUBSTITUTE($B2,"(","</s><s>")&"</s></t>","//s[last()]"),")","")
```

[image: FORMULA_SOLUTION]

Answer (score 2):

So here is a different version:

[image]

No error checking and very simple,find is used twice to get the position of the second bracket .
Mid uses find to get start and end.

Answer (score 2):

In case one has access to the new functions (currently in Beta):

```
=TEXTBEFORE(TEXTAFTER(A1,"(",-1),")")
```

Or:

```
=TAKE(TEXTSPLIT(A1,{"(",")"},,1),,-1)
```

Or:

```
=TEXTAFTER(SUBSTITUTE(A1,")",""),"(",-1)
```

Would all work.

Comment: Sir, you are enjoying all these new functions, when shall I, I am using O365 - Office Insider Beta Channel Version! Sir are you `MVP` ?

Comment: Sir, even my channel shows Version 2204 ( Build 15109.20000 Click-To-Run) but showing `#NAME?` strange. Good Sir you are sharing that we can learn at least.

Comment: @jvdv. FWIW these new functions are available to only _some_ Insiders on 2203 or later.  I'm on 2204 and do have them

Comment: @chrisneilsen, that's good news, meaning Ill keep hitting the "Check for Updates"-button.

Comment: @MayukhBhattacharya, I just got access. So you can update your Excel and check too. Maybe you are also lucky =)

Comment: @JvdV Sir, `Hallelujah` !!! Certainly, it shows, thank you its really `COOL` !!!

Comment: @JvdV Sir, tried this example, worked perfectly, I don't know how you manage to develop all these. Really lot of effort & research you do. `TEXTSPLIT()` has an optional for `[pad_width]`, what does it do sir?

Comment: @MayukhBhattacharya, that is a feature that would come in handy if you need to 'pad' data when you split into columns & rows. It's hard to give you an example, but you could try `=TEXTSPLIT("A B | C "," ","|",1,"No value")`

Comment: @JvdV Sir, worked, split into two Columns & Rows!

Comment: @JvdV Sir, may be I am wrong but I think there is something missing in the formula `TEXTBEFORE()` is this a bug?

Comment: To me it worked just fine @MayukhBhattacharya. No sure what you mean with "There is something missing".

Comment: @JvdV Sir, I am uploading the query within few, may I am not able to understand, but its baffling me a lot, so i want to know more clearly.!